# Навигация по заданным точкам Google Maps (Android) через Intent

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Каким образом можно передать `waypoints` в `Intent` карты?

Задача стоит такая: есть точка А, точка В и множество точек. Нужно проложить **оптимальный** маршрут **в навигаторе** от точки А в точку В, проходя по всем точкам (остальным).

На [странице с документацией](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) указаны возможные параметры для `Intent` с навигацией:

> **Parameters**
>
> **q:** Sets the end point for navigation searches. This can be a
>   latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query
>   string that returns more than one result, the first result will be
>   selected.
>
> **mode** sets the method of transportation. Mode is optional, defaults to
>   driving, and can be set to one of:
>
> **d** for driving
>
> **w** for walking
>
> **b** for bicycling avoid sets features the
>   route should try to avoid.
>
> **Avoid** is optional and can be set to one or
>   more of:
>
> **t** for tolls
>
> **h** for highways
>
> **f** for ferries

Но ничего не написано про то, как добавить еще точки, через которые нужно строить маршрут. Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ уже найден [здесь.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

Необходимо просто построить url с точками, например такой:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Киев,+Кибальчича,+21&waypoints=Киев,+Курнатовского,+8|Киев,+Запорожца,+21&travelmode=driving
```

И дальше, как и написано в [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents), вызвать карту:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Киев,+Кибальчича,+21&waypoints=Киев,+Курнатовского,+8|Киев,+Запорожца,+21&travelmode=driving");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

В итоге будет построен маршрут от текущего местоположения до указанной точки, проходя через множество указанных точек.